# Does JwPlayer supports Opera (with Presto) browser?

Tags: http-live-streaming, drm, jwplayer7, opera-presto

I am trying to play HLS content using JWPlayer on STB which has really old browser [Opera/9.80 (Linux mips) Presto/2.12.407], and I dint find any clear indication if JWPlayer supports such an old Opera.

```
jwplayer("player").setup({
      file: "http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/bbbfull/bbbfull.m3u8",
  width: "580",
  height: "370",
  type: "hls"
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

with jwplayer 6 & 7 you can have hls support on Desktop browser with premium key, but with old Opera Jwplayer must fallback to flash player

Answer (score 0):

JW Player 7 doesn't work in Presto, but JW Player 6 does. (Same is true of IE8.) In either case I think you'll need one of the paid versions to play HLS in Flash.

Comment: Is there any possibility that paid version of JW Player plays HLS in HTML but flash? STB dsnt support flash.

Comment: Only in browsers that support HLS natively, and in Chrome (on JW 7.4+). Some video game consoles have HLS support in their browsers (e.g. Wii U) but I don't think you'll get it working on the STB.